# How to access the model in step function of environment in rllib

Tags: reinforcement-learning, ray, rllib

I am using DQN algorithm and I need to obtain the (optimal) action related to a specific state in the step function of environment. Is there any way to do it?

```
# %% Env class
class SimpleEnv(gymnasium.Env):
    def __init__(self, env_config={'env_name': 'simple_cnn_env'}):
        self.env_name = env_config['env_name']
        self.action_space = gymnasium.spaces.Discrete(2)
        observation_space = gymnasium.spaces.Box(0.0 * np.ones(2, dtype=float),
                                              1.0 * np.ones(2, dtype=float),
                                              shape=(2,),
                                              dtype=float)
    def reset(self, *,
              seed=None, options=None):
        
        state = (np.array([0, 1]), np.zeros((21, 21, 3), dtype=np.uint8))
        self.timestep = 0
        return state, {}
    
    def _take_action(self, action):
        next_state = self.initial_state
        done = False if self.timestep <= 3 else True
        reward = 1 if done else 0
        return next_state, reward, done

    def step(self, action):
        self.timestep += 1
        state, reward, done = self._take_action(action)
        ## Here I need to obtain the action based on DQN (or every policy in general) for the current state ##
         ....
        return state, reward, done, False, {}

# %% Network
class SimpleConv(TorchModelV2, nn.Module, ABC):
    ### Here I define my network ######
    .....
```